# How to find Skew Projection Operator onto Plane parallel to some vector?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, linear-transformations, projection

I was trying to solve previous year question paper of competitive exam

In that I observed some strange question which I have not encountered before.

They had given one equation of plane and told to find operator which is skew projection parallel to some vector?

I know about orthogonal projection.

But Clearly this question is different I searched for reference I did not get

If anyone please tell me how to solve such a problem.Or reference which has such a problem

Any Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for the map $\mathbf x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)\mapsto \mathbf y=(y_1, y_2,y_3)$. Perhaps the easiest way to go is

1. Take a point $\mathbf x\in\Bbb R^n$ and find the parametric equation for the line through this point with the directional vector as the given vector of the projection.
2. Find the intersection of this line with the given plane. It is $\mathbf y$.