# To find the matrix of Skew projection along a vector.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

Let $P: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ be the skew projection onto the plane $$W = \{(x,y,z) \mid 3x+5y+2z=0\}$$ parallel to the vector $(0,-1,3)$.

We have to find the matrix of $P$ with respect to the standard basis.

---

I know orthogonal projection skew projection is new to me. Can someone please guide me?

---

I got a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3696589/how-to-find-skew-projection-operator-onto-plane-parallel-to-some-vector) but the idea is not clear to me since concrete problem was missing.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a vector $x$ which you want to translate parallel to $v$ so that it’s on the plane perpendicular to $w$, then you need some real $a$ so that $y=x-av$ satisfies $y\cdot w=0$.

Substituting for $y$: $x \cdot w= a v\cdot w$, so $a=x \cdot w / v\cdot w$.

Substituting for $a$ gives: $y= x- (x \cdot w / v\cdot w)v= (1 - (1/v\cdot w) vw^T)x$

Therefore, your desired matrix is $(1 - (1/v\cdot w) vw^T)$

Alternatively, you can shift to a coordinate system where the the vector is perpendicular to the plane and then use the standard projection matrix ($1-v v^T$) converted back into the coordinates you want.